# searching and sorting with paginate_by_sql -- will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using paginate_by_sql for a model's function.

```
 def index

@refprobes = Refprobe.paginate_by_sql ["select * from ref_probe
                                      where RPR_OID in
                                (SELECT DISTINCT RPR_OID
                                FROM REF_PROBE
                                JOIN ISH_PROBE ON RPR_OID = PRB_MAPROBE
                                JOIN ISH_SUBMISSION ON PRB_SUBMISSION_FK = SUB_OID
                                JOIN SEC_USER_PI ON USP_PI_ID = SUB_PI_FK
                                WHERE USP_USER_FK = " + session[:user_id]+ ")"], :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10

end
```

I want to add search and sorting to the above.

How do i do that?

Many many thanks

Comment: Use the code tag on your code, to make it readable.

Comment: Err, pls can u tell me how to use the code tag

Comment: when writing your post, select the code and click on the button with the binary code on it

Comment: Any help on this pls :) Most of the searches i found on the net are based on find(:all). I would like to know how to create a search form in the view page for a model with 'find_by_sql) and also how to do column sorting. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is quite old, but just came across it.

I guess you could always do something like this:

```
sql = <your existing sql>     
order = " ORDER BY #{params[:order]}"    
sql_to_paginate = sql + order
```

The other option would be to rewrite the query using Rails' syntax and then you could use the .reorder() method.

Hope this helps someone.